# why tasks.json: file format not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, format, vscode-tasks

I run VScode on ubuntu16, and test the helloworld.cpp.
At first, I walked through all, then I tried to edit the tasks.json.
I got the error. Ok, I cancel all the the change with rollback, it shows error aagin.
I remove the helloworld folder and try again the helloworld.
After Terminal > Configure Default Build Task and build, the error shows again.
What's the wrong? It is got from vscode.

The error message:

> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/liwenz/helloworld/.vscode/tasks.json -o /home/liwenz/helloworld/.vscode/tasks <

/usr/bin/ld:/home/liwenz/helloworld/.vscode/tasks.json: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/home/liwenz/helloworld/.vscode/tasks.json:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

the helloworld link is https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

Answer (score 10):

You have to switch from the tasks.json file to the actual code you want to compile or debug.

Answer (score 3):

As I build, I open tasks.json. So ${File}=tasks.json
I should open helloworld.cpp, then ${File}=helloword.cpp, and build ok.